# Can not install scrapy

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and want to create a Hello World project. And I can't install scrappy.

I try to install with settings and I get these errors

```
Collecting Scrappy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/df/dcd763f44aea90fbd58b4e7f7c8be95ade7d130cd21251fc0d93c295b1f0/Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.4.tar.gz
Collecting guessit (from Scrappy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/b4/fa5141d01f93191f9030a82e8528a6b8c5315059ea76e2e35d0cf3bef7f8/guessit-3.0.4.tar.gz
Collecting tvdb_api (from Scrappy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/c5/abcff2dd75e63daae3466fffd05a28428e57828f8b878125571a8e8343a8/tvdb_api-2.0.tar.gz
Collecting hachoir-metadata (from Scrappy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/89/f31ba1431ed7627032338cd009eaeb65dfad1311fa1437107c406fcb025e/hachoir-metadata-1.3.3.tar.gz

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Osman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\hachoir-metadata\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Osman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\hachoir-metadata\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hachoir-metadata\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hachoir-metadata\setup.py", line 65
        except OSError, err:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: try with: python -m pip install Scrapy

Answer (score 2):

I was trying also to install Scrapy and I figured out that the problem was Twisted dependency library, so first you have to install Twisted (not so easy), from [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) website download the right pre-compiled binary (if you have windows on 64-bit and python 3.5, for example, you will have to download Twisted‑19.2.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl ), from cmd after you enter in the folder where your binary download is:

```
python -m pip install  Twisted‑19.2.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl # change with your binary name
```

then you should install Scrapy easily

```
python -m pip install Scrapy
```

Comment: should work now, I did it myself. if doesn't work  make sure you have the 
 following  installation requirements https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/INSTALL.rst